# Show that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{(n+1)^p}$ converges and converges absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Show that the series

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{(n+1)^p}$

converges for $p > 0$ and converges absolutely for $p > 1$.

I'm a little confused on this. The fact that it's an alternating series is throwing me off.. should I be comparing it to the $p$-series of  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ ? I know that series converges by the comparison test, and if $p \le 1$ it diverges by comparison with the harmonic series since $\frac{1}{n^p} \ge \frac{1}{n}$.

Or should I be using a different method all together?

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely want to use two different methods for each part of the problem; you have been asked to prove two different statements, so it is not unreasonable to expect to use two methods.

For the first statement, that you have convergence when $p>0$, do you recall the Alternating Series Test?

For the second statement, that you have absolute convergence when $p>1$, you should write down the definition of what absolute convergence means, and then attempt to use the comparison test (maybe with a change of variables if you don't like the indexing) in order to get a proof.

Comment: So by the Alternating Series test, I have to show that if $a_{n+1} \le a_n$ and $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. The first property is true because as $n$ increases, the fraction is getting smaller and smaller since the denominator gets large. The second property holds for the essentially same reason, and the limit of the fraction goes to 0

Comment: Yes, but you will want to say things about $|a_n|$, depending on how you are defining the terms.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow...

Comment: It's just a technical consideration. If you have a series $\Sigma (-1)^n a_n$ you don't know if the $a_n$'s are all positive, so you consider their absolute values. I should add that the only cases in which the alternating series test works are when the $a_n$'s are all positive or all negative.